# InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) for skype url

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, invalidoperationexception

I was able to gather data from a web page using this

```
def code(self, response):
    code_loader = ItemLoader(item=SomeTestItem(), response=response)
    urls = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        page = response.urljoin(url)
        code_loader.add_value('urls', page)
        code_loader.add_value('codes', requests.get(page).status_code)
    return code_loader
```

when I try this to gather more data on the results of the above code I was presented with this error

```
2018-11-01 16:06:03 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.advich.com/zh/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/wes/wes/spiders/seo_spider.py", line 21, in parse
return itemloader.parse(response)
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/wes/wes/itemloader/itemloader.py", line 36, in parse
loaders.add_value('links', self.code(response))
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/wes/wes/itemloader/itemloader.py", line 100, in code
code_loader.add_value('codes', requests.get(page).status_code)
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 524, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 631, in send
adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
File "/Users/googleadwords/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 722, in get_adapter
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'skype:+8615050520029?chat'
```

I think this error is caused by the presence of `‘skype:+8615050520029?chat’` in the url. After testing this, I would like to ask how to solve this problem.

```
 result = requests.get('skype:+8615050520029?chat')---->

 No connection adapters were found for 'skype:+8615050520029?chat'
```

strat_url = 'https:\www.advich.com'
please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to exclude such urls in your `for` cycle or earlier in `urls = response.css('a:not([href*=skype]):not([href*=mailto])::attr(href)').extract()`.

Because you will have problem with making request to this "url".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, which provided me with a good idea.